# Ausrufezeichen nach Einzelwörtern - Ruf- oder Sonderfunktion?

Tags: word-usage, punctuation

Bei alten handschriftlichen Beschriftungen von Aktenordnern ( ~1960, die Beschriftenden waren *1900-1920) finde ich häufig, aber nicht immer, Ausrufezeichen hinter Worten, z.B. "Bank!", " Privat!", "Leitz!" (Bezug zum Arbeitgeber) oder "Sonstiges!". Wikipedia kennt hauptsächlich die Ausruf-Funktion, und die Verwendung in Burschenschaftsnamen (wobei ich dort immer davon ausging dass ein Rufen intendiert ist) - ist die Verwendung auf den Ordnern eine bekannte Nutzung, und was bedeutet es?

Comment: Beruht die Beobachtung auf Aktenordnern verschiedener Herkunft aus dieser Zeitspanne oder sind die nur von einer einzelnen Person / Firma?

Comment: 3 verschiedene Personen, die sich damals nicht kannten.

Comment: Sind diese Beschriftungen handschriftlich, also von konkreten Benutzern angefertigt? Oder sind sie gedruckt (also möglicherweise ab Werk so)? Ich frage, weil die Aufschrift "Leitz!" ja im Hausgebrauch wenig Sinn hätte. Ja, es handelt sich um einen Leitz-Ordner. Aber das würde man in der Regel als Benutzer nicht draufschreiben. (Anekdotisch ergänzend: Im slavischsprachigen Raum Europas fand man - besonders im Sozialismus - Schulhefte, auf denen groß "Schulheft" gedruckt stand und Aktendeckel, auf denen groß "Aktendeckel" (natürlich in der jeweiligen Sprache) stand - ab Werk. Seltsam.)

Comment: Sicher ein Ausrufezeichen, Leitz bezog sich auf den Arbeitgeber; Handschriftlich angefertigt.

Comment: Das ist ein Ordner, hergestellt von der Firma Leitz, und benützt von einem Mitarbeiter der Firma Leitz, und beschriftet mit "Leitz!"? Die Geschichte wird immer verzwickter...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann ... und darin: Listen chinesischer, gereizter, laizistischer Leitzianer. The plot thickens...

Answer (score 2):

Das Ausrufezeichen für sich alleine wird genommen, wenn man auf etwas aufmerksam machen möchte, also eine Kurzform für

## Achtung!  [image]

Es könnte also sein, dass man **wichtigen Inhalt** mit einem zusätzlichen Ausrufezeichen beschriftet hat.

Comment: Deine Hinzufügung in Klammern macht die Erklärung aber wieder zunichte. Wenn es eh klar ist, dass die Papiere wichtig sind (weil, sonst hätte man sie nicht aufbewahrt), dann ist das Rufzeichen auf dem Ordnerrücken ja funktionslos. Funktion hätte es nur, wenn es auch Aktenordner mit unwichtigem Inhalt gäbe. Was also? Hüh oder hott?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Wenn es häufig, aber nicht immer, ist muss man sich halt überlegen, was in den Ordnern ohne Ausrufezeichen drin ist... da können wir leider nur raten.

Comment: Ich denke die Bedeutung eines allein stehenden Ausrufezeichens als "wichtig" ist hier das entscheidende. Auch der in der Frage genannte Wikipedia-Artikel nennt diese Bedeutung. Dann wäre die Erklärung, dass die Ordnerbeschriftung auf wichtige Inhalte hinweisen soll.

Answer (score 0):

Es handelt sich wohl um eine eine persönliche Marotte des ursprünglichen Besitzers der Aktenordner. Auffällig ist allerdings, wie wir aus einem Kommentar lernen, dass mehrere Personen, die sich nicht kannten, dies so praktiziert haben sollen. Vielleicht war es also eine verbreitete Marotte?

Psychologisch kann ich mir die Entstehung durchaus auch aus eigener Praxis des Aktenordnerbeschriftens erklären.

Theorie 1:

Setzt man ein Ausrufezeichen nach dem Titelwort, so ergibt sich sowohl beim Schreiben wie beim Lesen eine Art abschließendes, gefühltes "So, das wäre geschafft!" oder auch beim Suchen: "So, das wäre gefunden!". Sowohl das Beschriften als auch das Suchen von Aktenordnern ist ja oft durch eine gewisse innere Anspannung charakterisiert: "Aufpassen, dass ich mich nicht verschreibe!" oder "Wo zum Teufel ist jetzt wieder der Ordner mit den Banksachen?". Das Ausrufezeichen drückt diese Anspannung oder besondere psychische Prominenz aus.

Theorie 2:

Der Besitzer oder die Besitzerin kann das Rufzeichen auch verwendet haben, um Ordner mit als besonders wichtig eingestuften Sammelgebieten zu kennzeichnen. Sie heben sich mit dem Rufzeichen ab von Ordnern mit weniger wichtigem Inhalt. Zum Beispiel würdest du vermutlich kaum einen Ordner finden, der

> Sonstiger Krimskrams!

beschriftet ist. Eher noch würde man finden

> Sonstiger Krimskrams...

wobei die drei Punkte die Offenheit der Sammlung ausdrücken.

Comment: Klingt gut, es gibt aber tatsächlich einen "Sonstiges!"-Ordner

Comment: @bukwyrm  Dann ist vielleicht Theorie 1 hier besser?